# Most concise J syntax for creating a numeric matrix

Tags: j

Imagine that I want to take the numbers from 1 to 3 and form a matrix such that each possible pairing is represented, e.g.,

```
1 1
1 2
1 3
2 1
2 2
2 3
3 1
3 2
3 3
```

Here is the monadic verb I formulated in J to do this:

```
($~ (-:@# , 2:)) , ,"0/~ 1+i.y
```

Originally I had thought that `,"0/~ 1+i.y` would be sufficient, but unfortunately that produces the following output:

```
1 1
1 2
1 3

2 1
2 2
2 3

3 1
3 2
3 3
```

In other words, its shape is 3 3 2 and I want something whose shape is 9 2. The only way I could think of to fix it is to pour all of the data into a new shape. I'm convinced there must be a more concise way to do this. Anyone know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way (which uses `{` as a monad in its capacity for permutation cataloguing):

```
>,{ 2#<1+i.y
```

EDIT:

Some fun to be had with this scheme:

All possible permutations:

```
>,{ y#<1+i.y
```

Configurable number in sequence:

```
>,{ x#<1+i.y
```

Comment: Very cool! I just spent a while playing around with `{` and figuring out the meaning of the above syntax, which is now crystal clear to me. I'll wait a few days to see if there are any even more concise answers, but my guess is you've probably nailed this one. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I can rarely find a good use for `{`, and I find it does not always do what I want, but against the same list it works well.

Comment: Yeah, J is not SO's most popular language. Nor is it my favourite. The J community is closely clustered around jsoftware.com, but usually there any question like this spins out of control and expands into a myriad replies on fringe optimisation and special code.

Comment: I don't think I have a favorite programming language, though J is among my favorites. It has definitely expanded my horizons as a developer.

Comment: @GregoryHigley Most of what I do for work is J. J is great for math and matrixes and stuff, but not so much for data modelling, GUI, communication, etc. When you use it as a specialised tool, ok, but as a do-it-all tool, not so much.

Comment: I agree completely. I see J being useful as an embedded, domain-specific language, but I couldn't see doing much else with it.

Answer (score 5):

Reshaping your intermediate result can be simplified. Removing the topmost axis is commonly done with `,/` so in your case the completed phrase could be `,/ ,"0/~ 1+i.y`

Comment: Now that I've looked into it, it appears that the result of `,/` is to create a result whose shape is equal to the multiplication of the top two axes, e.g., if you apply `,/` to something whose shape is 7 4 2, it becomes 28 2. That's really useful! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this question is old, but there is a simpler way to do it: count to 9 in trinary, and add 1.

```
   1 + 3 3 #: i.9
1 1
1 2
1 3
2 1
2 2
2 3
3 1
3 2
3 3
```

The `3 3 & #:` gives you two digits. The general 'base 3' verb is `3 & #.^:_1`.

Comment: But my question only used 3 as an example. I was trying to create a general verb that would work with any number. (Of course, there's a practical limit.) Despite that, your idea is very interesting.

Comment: Actually, it *does* work for any number. You're asking for every combination of k items drawn from a pool of n, with replacement. The size of this set is n^k. Let's write this ` R=:^~ ` in j. For example, `4 R 10` is 10^4, or 10000, and you can enumerate them by counting from 0000 to 9999 in base 10. `# 8 R 2` is 2^8, which is why bytes range from 00000000..11111111 in binary. Or the same thing in hex: `# 2 R 16`  = 00..FF. Basically, give each item in the base set its own digit (0..n-1), and then list all the k-digit numbers (including the smaller numbers, padded with 0).